# Displaying Portfolio Filter by Category Order (alphabetically)

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, order

I have created a custom post type to display churches in Europe. I used a [tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-filterable-portfolio-with-wordpress-and-jquery/) to make it filterable and everything on [my site](http://globalicn.com/preview/regions/europe/) works as normal.

How would I organize the posts by **country**, instead of by title?

```
$loop = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'europe',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'asc'
    )
);
$count = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that 'country' is a custom meta field. In that case, you need this ([very much like one of the examples in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)):

```
$loop = new WP_Query( 
    array ( 
        'post_type' => 'europe', 
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
        'meta_key' => 'country' 
        'order' => 'asc'
    ) 
);
```